# How to set column headers to the first row in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I set the column header of a dataframe to the first row of a dataframe and reset the column names?

```
# Creation of dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["1", "4", "7"],
                   "B": ["2", "5", "8"],
                   "C": ['3','6','9']})

# df:

   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

Desired Outcome:

```
   0  1  2
0  A  B  C
1  1  2  3
2  4  5  6
3  7  8  9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is similar to `reset_index` but on the other axis. Unfortunately, there is no `axis` parameter in `reset_index`.

But, you can cheat a bit and apply a double transposition to handle the columns as index temporarily:

```
df.T.reset_index().T.reset_index(drop=True)
```

output:

```
   0  1  2
0  A  B  C
1  1  2  3
2  4  5  6
3  7  8  9
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`Index.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_frame.html) with transpose for one row `DataFrame` and last set columns names by `range`:

```
df = pd.concat([df.columns.to_frame().T, df], ignore_index=True)
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
print (df)
   0  1  2
0  A  B  C
1  1  2  3
2  4  5  6
3  7  8  9
```

Or use [`DataFrame.set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html) for chained method solution:

```
df = (pd.concat([df.columns.to_frame().T, df], ignore_index=True)
        .set_axis(range(len(df.columns)), axis=1))
```

Comment: I got an error message: "AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'to_frame'"

Comment: @Denzyl - what is your pandas version?

Comment: my pandas version is 0.20.1

Comment: @Denzyl - it is old, is possible upgrade?

Comment: unfortunately 0.20.1 is the latest I have access to due to restrictions

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.vstack` on a list of column names and the DataFrame to create an array with one extra row; then cast it into `pd.DataFrame`:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df.columns, df]))
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2
0  A  B  C
1  1  2  3
2  4  5  6
3  7  8  9
```

Comment: @jezrael right but everything in `df` are already strings.